# How to pass in String property to WCF and return a dataset?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, dataset

The program returns **System.Data.DataSet**. I want the items of the data set returned.

I have a database with 4 tables: `Bands`, `Festivals`, `Stages`; and a junction table - `Band_Festival`.

The sql queries all work when executed and a `DataGridView` on the form displays the correct records.

I'm trying to have WCF retrieve the data and return a `DataSet` or `list<DataSet>` to the Form.

A selected `ComboBox` item on the form should be passed to wcf when a call is made, which is used as a parameter for the SQL query.

`String Festivals {get; set;}
 ComboBox.SelectedItem = Festivals`

is used to pass in the parameter to the sql query.

When the sql query's WHERE condition is `festival_name = 'Boomtown Fair'` the call returns **"System.Data.DataSet"**, I  want the list of items. When the condition is `festival_name = @festival` with `Parameters.AddValue("@festival", Festivals)` An Exception is thrown with **"Parameter not supplied"**

Here's some code:

**Form**

```
String Festivals { get; set; }

    FestivalsBandsServiceReference.FestivalBandsServiceClient ws = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComBoxFestivals.SelectedItem = Festivals;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ws = new FestivalsBandsServiceReference.FestivalBandsServiceClient();
    }
    private void comBoxFestivals_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<String> festival = ws.GenerateNewBandList(Festivals);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("," ,festival));
    }
```

**FestivalBandsService.svc.cs**

```
public List<DataSet> GenerateNewBandList(String Festivals)
    {

        List<DataSet> bands = new List<DataSet>();

        string dataSource = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = " +
                       @"D:\WCFFestivalBands\WCFFestivalBands\App_Data\FestivalBands.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30";


        //Create new instance of sql connection, pass in the connection string for FestivalBands.mdf to connect to database.
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dataSource);

        string sqlQuerySelectBands = "SELECT Bands.Band_Name FROM Band_Festival JOIN dbo.Bands ON Bands.Band_ID =" +
                                  "Band_Festival.Band_ID JOIN dbo.Festival ON Festival.Festival_ID " +
                                  "= Band_Festival.Festival_ID WHERE Festival_Name = @festival";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuerySelectBands, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@festival", Festivals);

        conn.Open();

        //Create new instance of DataAdpater to retrieve the data pass in Sql command
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        //Create new instance of dataSet to hold the data retrieved from sql query
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        //using DataAdapter fill in dataSet wiht data if user input and stored data matches
        da.Fill(ds);

        bands.Add(ds);

        return bands;
    }
}
```

**IFestivalBandsService.cs**

```
     [ServiceContract]
public interface IFestivalBandsService
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    List<DataSet> GenerateNewBandList(String Festivals);
}
```

This is pretty new. Only just learnt how to pass and return values using WCF. Passing a list from a dataSet is next level. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I haven't added the tables colums or rows, not sure if its relevent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code snippets, I copy and test it locally, it seems that there are no errors in your WCF server end. Otherwise, it will not succeed when you hard-code SQL statement to query your database.  But I could not find the process you initialize your Festivals property when you consuming the service in the client-side.

> String Festivals { get; set; }
>   ComBoxFestivals.SelectedItem = Festivals;

these code snippest may be the reason caused your issue.
In .net 4.6+ you could refer to the following code to set up the default of the property.

```
public int Price { get; set; } = 100;
```

or you could refer to the following code.

```
    class Product
    {
        private string name = "Apple";
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can return a `List<DataSet>` from WCF, the DataSet could be anything and it wouldn't know how to serialize it.

What we do for transporting is use a DTO (Data Transport Object). Basically this is just a fancy way of saying, creating a concrete class and making sure it is marked with `DataContract` attribute, and each property is mark with a `DataMember` Attribute where appropriate . E.g

```
[DataContract]
public class PurchaseOrder
{

    // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
    [DataMember]
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set
}
```

Read more about them here

[Using Data Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts)